# What $() syntax means for Groovy language?

Tags: groovy

I found this in [Groovy Syntax documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#) at [4.6.1. Special cases](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_special_cases):

> As slashy strings were mostly designed to make regexp easier so a few
> things that are errors in GStrings like $() or $5 will work with
> slashy strings.

What `$()` syntax means? give some usage examples please

I also found it at [Define the Contract Locally in the Repository of the Fraud Detection Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-cdc-consumer-define):

> ```
>     body([ // (4)
>            "client.id": $(regex('[0-9]{10}')),
>            loanAmount : 99999
>     ])
> ```

but I don't understand what `$()` means when used with `regex('[0-9]{10}')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means nothing (or what you make of it).  There are two places, you
are addressing, but they have nothing to do with each other.

The docs just mention this as "you can use slashy strings to write
things, that would give you an error with a GString" - the same is true
for just using `'`-Strings.

E.g.

```
"hello $()"
```

Gives this error:

```
unknown recognition error type: groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.LexerNoViableAltException
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/tmp/x.groovy: 1: token recognition error at: '(' @ line 1, column 9.
   "hello $()"
```

The parser either wants a `{` or any char, that is a valid first char
for a variable (neither `(` nor `5` is).

The other place you encountered `$()` (in Spring cloud contract), this
is just a function with the name `$`.

Form the docs [8. Contract DSL](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.0.x/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_dynamic_properties_inside_the_body):

> You can set the properties inside the body either with the `value` method or, if you use the Groovy map notation, with `$()`

So this is just a function, with a very short name.

E.g. you can try this yourself:

```
void $(x) { println x }
$("Hello")
```